# Локализация ЯКарт

Tags: яндекс-карты

Всем привет. Необходимо сделать карту на китайском языке. Гугл стал платным, а, судя по докам, ЯКарты не могут в китайскую локаль. Может кто знает, есть какая возможность подключить сторонний сервис или ещё каким образом перевести ЯКарты на китайский? Спасибо.

Comment: "Гугл стал платным" - не скажете, что именно там стало платно? Вроде юзаю гугл карты и пока всё устраивает...

Comment: @Kvilios поищите. Если коротко, то урезали лимиты и подняли цены. Сайт для кота может и вписывается в лимиты, но более-менее посещаемый сайт «попадает». Например https://habr.com/ru/post/417715/

Comment: А не думали использовать карты baidu? Там сложно продраться через нелокализованную документацию, но раньше примеры были норм и если карта для китайской аудитории, то это самый привычный вариант: http://lbsyun.baidu.com/products/products/map

Comment: @Reni спасибо за информацию, но тут соль в том, чтобы можно было переключаться между русским и китайским. Но, если честно, в сторону карт страны, язык которой нужен - я даже не думал. Спасибо ещё раз)

Comment: @Илья в крайнем случае можно при переключении языка полностью менять карту. Ещё мне казалось, что у OSM есть и китайская и русскоязычная карты.

Answer (score 1):

В API Яндекс.Карт, к сожалению, нет китайской локализации - поскольку подложка растровая, то и границы, и подписи могут быть только на одном из поддерживаемых языков. Отдельной проблемой может стать поиск по карте, если такая функция вам нужна.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! Значит, придётся как-то изголяться с гугл картами. Похоже, договорились пока на статичные точки на картах из файлика. Они, вроде как, бесплатные... Пока)